# yii qtip extension not working

Tags: jquery, yii, qtip2, yii-extensions

I am trying to use YII qtip extension.

```
Yii::import('ext.qtip.QTip');
$qtip = new QTip(array(
    'options' => array(
        'content' => 'A nice progress bar',
        'position' => array(
            'corner' => array(
                'target' => 'topMiddle',
                'tooltip' => 'bottomLeft'
            )
        ),
        'show' => array(
            'when' => array('event' => 'mouseover' ),
            'effect' => array( 'length' => 300 )
        ),
        'hide' => array(
            'when' => array('event' => 'mouseout' ),
            'effect' => array( 'length' => 300 )
        ),
    )
));

$qtip->addQTip('i', array(
    'style' => array('tip' => 'bottomLeft', 'name' => 'dark')
));
```

I can see that qtip script file is loaded in the browser and also code for qtip is generated. But qtips are not coming.
Can anyone help me with this? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the console? (ctrl + shift + i in chrome)

Comment: No javascript errors....Infact when I run the code generated in the browser by this extension in console....qtip is appearing

Comment: The same problem is occurring to me. Have you solved it since 2012?